# How can I asynchronously get data from many websites, and add them to a collection?

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

I am trying to call many different web services at the same time and aggregating the data.

My intention is to create a Task for each web call, pass a shared container to each task, and store data from each call in the container. As long as I can get data from each web call into the shared container, I am happy.

I have created an example of what I'm trying to do - however, it sometimes crashes with an exception on the Task.WaitAll line: "One or more errors occurred. (Source array was not long enough. Check the source index, length, and the array's lower bounds.
Parameter name: sourceArray)".

I am new to using async/await and multithreading.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting tasks...");
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
            List<char> container = new List<char>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++)
            {
                tasks.Add(LongTask(container));
            }
            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine("Checkpoint 1.");
            Console.WriteLine("Tasks Finished");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static async Task<string> LongTask(List<char> container)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var text = await client.GetAsync("http://www.google.com");

            var myList = text.StatusCode.ToString().ToList();

            container.AddRange(myList);

            return text.StatusCode.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: List<char>.AddRange( ) is not thread-safe.  Have you tried using something like ConcurrentBag?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiple awaits vs Task.WaitAll - equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32119507/multiple-awaits-vs-task-waitall-equivalent)

Comment: please have look to answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can make use of `lock` construct around current list when adding data that will also work.

below will go at class level

```
private static object _lock = new object();
```

this will go in your method

```
var myList = text.StatusCode.ToString().ToList();
lock(_lock)
{
  container.AddRange(myList);
}
```

---

or You can make use of [ConcurrentBag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1?view=netframework-4.7.1)

so in you code replace List by this , in main method

```
ConcurrentBag<string> container = new ConcurrentBag<string>();
```

and in the LongTask( method do as below.

```
 var myList = text.StatusCode.ToString().ToList();               
 container.AddRange(myList);
```

here I am suggesting you list of string as `ConcurrentBag` doenst have `AddRange` method and if you do write `foreach` to add in `ConcurrentBag` than might be chance other thread also add `char` in between , instead of that once all get completed you can take `string` out of `ConcurrentBag` and convert it into char array or list.

**Note:**  `ConcurrentBag<T>` is a thread-safe bag implementation, optimized for scenarios where the same thread will be both producing and consuming data stored in the bag.

Comment: This is not a good use of ConcurrentBag as the internal implementation is designed to solve a very specific problem where a thread adding to the bag is almost always the one that retrieves the items it added. A list and a lock as you also state is a more efficient solution

Comment: @RichardBlewett - just updaed answer