# Difference in Task.WaitAll(result1, result2) and await result1; await result2;

Tags: c#, unit-testing, vs-unit-testing-framework

We had a test case which had earlier below snippet written but the test case was failing due to race condition.

```
Task.WaitAll(result1, result2);
```

But when it changed to below it started working fine.

```
await result1; await result2;
```

Note: also we marked Test case as Async too but I don't think it makes any difference since I checked all test run async alphabetically anyway by Microsoft Unit Test framework.

Comment: Have you tried using `await Task.WhenAll(...)` instead of `Task.WaitAll(...)`. [See other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123406/waitall-vs-whenall)

Comment: Also keep the exception handling of `WhenAll()` in mind ([see here](https://alt-dev.com.au/why-you-may-be-doing-async-wrong-in-c#heading-waitall-waits-for-all-tasks-to-complete))

Answer (score 1):

`Task.WaitAll(result1, result2);` is Blocking Call. it means that your current thread is blocked until your task is Done.

`await` is a non-blocking call: it means that your current Thread will not blocked.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await

[multiple awaits vs Task.WaitAll - equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32119507/multiple-awaits-vs-task-waitall-equivalent)