# Task.WhenAll().ContinueWith() throws unexpected Task Canceled exception

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, continuations

I am using `Task.WhenAll` to schedule tasks concurrently (more or less of course) and want to rethrow all exceptions rather than the first one what `Task.WhenAll` would do.
So I want to perfor a continuation whenever any child task faulted or has been canceled.
That's what `NotOnRanToCompletion` means, right?

Well this actually works but in case that all Tasks actually have completed,
I get a Task Cancelled exception on the Continuation?

```
var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(10);
var tasks = portList.Select(async port =>
{
    try
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();
        await this.AddDeviceAsync(bioprocessDevicesDto, template, port);
    }
    finally
    {
        semaphore.Release();
    }
});
await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ContinueWith(t =>
{
    // this will make all inner exceptions available
    // never null
    throw t.Exception;
}, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnRanToCompletion).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

[image: Visual Studio screenshot]

Comment: Please, do not post code as images

Comment: From the documentation: "If the criteria specified through the `continuationOptions` parameter are not met, the continuation task will be canceled instead of scheduled."

Comment: oh boy really? I did not find that. I must have been asleep. Well that pretty much explains it. I actually did not expect this kind of behaviour but well what can I say

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever seems you have an answer here

Comment: In this case I will use TaskContinuationOptions.None and rethow Exception if !=null. Is checking for Task.Status!=RanToCompletion necessary here?

Comment: another option is to actually write `catch` block and hendle exception there, so your task will run to its end

Answer (score 2):

That behavior is by-design and [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith).

Note that your code is not `await`ing the task returned from `WhenAll`; it's `await`ing the *continuation* from `ContinueWith`.

[`ContinueWith` is a low-level method with dangerous default behavior](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html). Use `await` instead:

```
var tasks = portList.Select(...);
var allTask = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
try { await allTask; }
catch { throw allTask.Exception; }
```

Comment: hmm that's interesting. all my tests worked as expected with the .ContinueWith() approach. on the other hand my tests revealed that (your) classic try{}catch{} approach just behaves the same like withouht try{}catch{} : only the very first exception will be thrown! how do I get all exceptions then?

Comment: It works fine for me. Without the `try`/`catch`, the first exception is raised from this code; with the `try`/`catch`, an `AggregateException` is raised from this code.

Comment: Yes it does work fine. I made a mistake beforel. I will move this try catch logic to an Task Extension Method 'PreserveAllExceptions' that uses allTasks as parameter so I can use it like this:                 await Task.WhenAll(tasks).PreserveAllExceptions().ConfigureAwait(false);

Comment: Hmmm... I really like the idea of that extension method!

Comment: @yBother you might find this interesting: [I want await to throw AggregateException, not just the first Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18314961/i-want-await-to-throw-aggregateexception-not-just-the-first-exception).

Answer (score 1):

When you look at the [TaskContinuationOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcontinuationoptions?view=netframework-4.8) for `NotOnRanToCompletion`, it states:

> This option is not valid for multi-task continuations.

I would try changing `NotOnRanToCompletion` to another option that handles multi-task continuations.