# How can you catch a RequestFailedException if making multiple DownloadToAsync calls in parallel?

Tags: c#, async-await, azure-blob-storage

I've got some code like this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Response>> SaveFiles(IEnumerable<string> filePaths)
{
    var baseFolder = "C:\\Temp";
    var fullTempPath = $"{baseFolder}\\{Guid.NewGuid()}";
    var fileDirectory = Directory.CreateDirectory(fullTempPath);

    Task<Response>[] tasks = new Task<Response>[filePaths.Count()];

    for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.Count(); i++)
    {
        var blobClientDetails = GetBlobClientDetails(filePaths.ElementAt(i));
        var credentials = new AzureSasCredential(blobClientDetails.Value);
        var blob = new BlobClient(blobClientDetails.Key, credentials);
        tasks[i] = blob.DownloadToAsync(fileDirectory.FullName);
    }

    return await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

private KeyValuePair<Uri, string> GetBlobClientDetails(string filePath)
{
    var filePathExcludingSAS = filePath.Substring(0, filePath.IndexOf('?'));
    var sasToken = filePath.Substring(filePath.IndexOf('?') + 1);

    return new KeyValuePair<Uri, string>(new Uri(filePathExcludingSAS), sasToken);
}
```

The theory is that this will trigger the download of each file before waiting for the download of the previous one to complete, hence the `Task.WhenAll(tasks)` at the end. However, I want to be able to accurately catch an exception and be able to specify which file failed to download. How can I do that?

Comment: Is this helpful at all? [I want await to throw AggregateException, not just the first Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18314961/i-want-await-to-throw-aggregateexception-not-just-the-first-exception)

Comment: This seems to suggest that AggregateException would catch all and then return just the first error. I was hoping there would be some way to wrap Task.WhenAll() in a try catch and the RequestFailedException would be caught and I could somehow identify the file from the exception, but it looks like the exception only returns a error code that might be of use.

Comment: Would you be interested in a solution that wraps the `RequestFailedException` in some custom `Exception`-derived type, that has a `FilePath` property, and exposes the original `RequestFailedException` as its `InnerException` property?

Comment: I'd be interested to see how that would work, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Theodor for your help thus far. I've created something like this, which is currently untested and I wonder if it will be truly async.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<DownloadResult>> SaveFiles(IEnumerable<string> filePaths)
{
    var baseFolder = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tempFolderLocation"];
    var fullTempPath = $"{baseFolder}\\{Guid.NewGuid()}";
    var fileDirectory = Directory.CreateDirectory(fullTempPath);
    var tasks = filePaths.Select(fp => DownloadFile(fp, fileDirectory.FullName));
    return await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

I've added a 'DownloadFile' method that now does it for each file and returns a task:

```
private async Task<DownloadResult> DownloadFile(string filePath, string directory)
{
    var blobClientDetails = GetBlobClientDetails(filePath);
    var credentials = new AzureSasCredential(blobClientDetails.Value);
    var blob = new BlobClient(blobClientDetails.Key, credentials);

    try
    {
        var response = await blob.DownloadToAsync(directory);
        return new DownloadResult(true, response);
    }
    catch (RequestFailedException ex)
    {
        // do some additional logging of the exception.
        return new DownloadResult(false, null, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Here's DownloadResult:

```
public class DownloadResult
{
    public DownloadResult(bool isSuccessful, Response response, string errorMessage = "")
    {
        IsSuccessful = isSuccessful;
        Response = response;
        ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
    }

    public bool IsSuccessful { get; set; }
    public Response Response { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yeap, this approach should work just as well.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias My only concern is would this still download the files in parallel or would the await in the DownloadFile method mean it would only download 1 file at a time.

Comment: All the files will be downloaded concurrently. That's the magic of async/await. It is composable.

Answer (score 2):

The LINQ [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select) operator makes it easy to project native tasks to custom tasks, that have some extra functionality. In this case the extra functionality is wrapping the [`RequestFailedException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.requestfailedexception)s in a custom exception type:

```
public async Task<Response[]> SaveFiles(IEnumerable<string> filePaths)
{
    var baseFolder = "C:\\Temp";
    var fullTempPath = $"{baseFolder}\\{Guid.NewGuid()}";
    var fileDirectory = Directory.CreateDirectory(fullTempPath);

    Task<Response>[] tasks = filePaths.Select(async filePath =>
    {
        var blobClientDetails = GetBlobClientDetails(filePath);
        var credentials = new AzureSasCredential(blobClientDetails.Value);
        var blob = new BlobClient(blobClientDetails.Key, credentials);
        try
        {
            return await blob.DownloadToAsync(fileDirectory.FullName);
        }
        catch (RequestFailedException ex)
        {
            throw new FileDownloadException(ex.Message, ex) { FilePath = filePath };
        }
    }).ToArray();

    Task<Response[]> whenAll = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    try { return await whenAll; }
    catch { whenAll.Wait(); throw; } // Propagate AggregateException
}
```

The `FileDownloadException` class:

```
public class FileDownloadException : Exception
{
    public string FilePath { get; init; }
    public FileDownloadException(string message, Exception innerException)
        : base(message, innerException) { }
}
```

You could then consume the `SaveFiles` method like this:

```
try
{
    Response[] responses = await SaveFiles(filePaths);
}
catch (AggregateException aex)
{
    foreach (var ex in aex.InnerExceptions)
    {
        if (ex is FileDownloadException fileEx)
        {
            // Our special exception wrapper
            Console.WriteLine($"{fileEx.FilePath} => {fileEx.InnerException.Message}");
        }
        else
        {
            // Something else happened (not a RequestFailedException)
            Console.WriteLine($"{ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was just working on something similar, however I opted for a DownloadResult object that returned a success / failure, with content and error if there was one. I'll post what I have as it may not work as I expect.

Comment: @sr28 you could also store the `FilePath` information directly in the the `RequestFailedException` instance, using the [`Exception.Data`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.data) property. This way it would not be as structured and type-safe, but you would write less code.

Comment: Yes, that might be an option. I've taken the idea of using LINQ Select but splitting the actions. Take a look at my answer and see what you think.

Comment: @sr28 it's OK. Whether you use anonymous lambdas or named functions is a matter of personal taste.