# How to get details about an error from RequestFailedException

Tags: migration, azure-storage

I am trying to port code that had been using `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` classes to use the newer classes in `Azure.Data.Tables`, `Azure.Storage.Queues`, etc.  From what I have been able to discern, the `StorageException` class has been replaced by `RequestFailedException`.  Unfortunately, there are some properties in `StorageException` that do not exist in `RequestFailedException`, making it difficult to log appropriate messages when an exception is encountered (for example: `RequestId`, `RequestInformation`, etc.).

The migration document does not address the differences between `StorageException` and the new `RequestFailedException`, or how to get error details from it.

It seems that either the new libraries are not yet mature enough for prime time, or maybe it is just because the documentation is lacking the relevant information and I can't find the appropriate methodologies for getting all of the error information from the `RequestFailedException`.

Does anyone know how to get more data out of the new class?  Here are some examples of what we used to do:

```
catch (StorageException e)
{
    operation.Telemetry.Properties.Add("AzureServiceRequestID", e.RequestInformation.ServiceRequestID);
```

Changing the above to use `RequestFailedException` is a problem because `RequestInformation` is not a property of `RequestFailedException`.

Here is another case:

```
catch (StorageException se)
{
    var ri = se.RequestInformation;
    if (ri.ErrorCode == "TableNotFound")
    {
        Logger.Info(
            $"{SJResult.MakeInfo(64)} {ri.HttpStatusCode} {ri.HttpStatusMessage}, Storage Service code={ri.ErrorCode} This is OK if HL7 has not yet received messages."); // 60240040
    }
    else
    {
        Logger.Error(
            $"{SJResult.MakeError(65)} HttpStatusCode: {ri.HttpStatusCode}, HttpStatusMessage: {ri.HttpStatusMessage}, Storage Service code={ri.ErrorCode}, " +
            $"Extended.ErrorCode: {ri.ExtendedErrorInformation.ErrorCode} Extended.ErrorMessage: {ri.ExtendedErrorInformation.ErrorMessage}"); // E0240041 
        throw;
    }
```

Again, `RequestInformation` is not available in `RequestFailedException`.

How do we get access to all the detailed information (`RequestInformation`) about an exception from the new `RequestFailedException` class?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see the definition of [RequestFailedException Class (Azure)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.requestfailedexception?view=azure-dotnet) and constuctors in the latest version of azure sdk.

[RequestFailedException(Int32, String, String, Exception)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.requestfailedexception.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet#azure-requestfailedexception-ctor(system-int32-system-string-system-string-system-exception))    : gives   ***HTTP status code ,specified error message, error code, and a reference to the **inner exception** .***

And
[RequestFailedException(Response)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.requestfailedexception.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet#azure-requestfailedexception-ctor(azure-response))
Gives  *****error message**, **HTTP status code**, error code*** obtained from the specified response.

The [***response***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.response?view=azure-dotnet) in the argument represents the HTTP response from the service which has ***`ClientRequestId`*** as one of the properties as shown in the table which gets  client request id that was sent to server in the form of  ***`x-ms-client-request-id`*** **headers**.You can try the same while catching the error in the try-catch block.

[image]

In exception class you can give

```
public class RequestFailedException : Exception
{
...
    public RequestFailedException(int status, string message, string? errorCode, Exception? innerException)        : base(message , innerException) { }
}
```

Or use *RequestFailedException(Response)*  from which you can get ClientRequestId.

I’ve not tested it myself, but please check if below can be worked around which is taken from  the below references  or check if  something similar can give an idea.Also see if content property can be retrieved as a part of response.

```
try
{
  ...
      }
catch (Exception aex)
{
    foreach (var ex in aex.InnerExceptions)
    {
        if (ex is RequestFailedException except)
        {
        var innerException = excep.InnerException;
        if (innerException != null && innerException.GetType() == typeof(WebException))
        {
          WebException webEx = innerException as WebException;
          WebResponse resp = webEx.Response;
          var responseHeaders = resp.Headers;
          string requestId = responseHeaders["x-ms-request-id"];
          Console.WriteLine("Request Id: " + requestId);
            Console.WriteLine(except.InnerException.Message);
        }
        else
        {
            //  (not a RequestFailedException)
            Console.WriteLine($"{ex.Message}");
        }
    }
```

***References:***

1. [How can I get Request ID when an exception occurs? (microsoft.com)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b56e14f7-eb02-466b-9288-7902ae0b0ace/how-can-i-get-request-id-when-an-exception-occurs)
2. [c# - How can you catch a RequestFailedException if making multiple
   DownloadToAsync calls in parallel? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68102901/how-can-you-catch-a-requestfailedexception-if-making-multiple-downloadtoasync-ca)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my simple solution, somewhat based on kavya's answer...

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (ex.InnerException is Azure.RequestFailedException rfex)
    {
        //let's create a custom error message so as not to expose sensitive information to the user
        var status = rfex.Status;   // ((Azure.RequestFailedException)ex.InnerException).Status;
        var errorCode = rfex.ErrorCode; // ((Azure.RequestFailedException)ex.InnerException).ErrorCode;
        string exmsg = $"Error is: {ex.Message}\nStatus: {status}\nError Code: {errorCode}";
        throw new Exception(exmsg);
    }
}
```