# Handle errors from a task awaited later on

Tags: c#, async-await

I want to trigger some action running a Task-returning function then run some other async function and at the end await the first task and handle exceptions if any.
Because I cannot be sure if my function is async (throwing exception will be postponed until I call `await`) or non-async (any exception will be thrown immediately) I came up to this solution. But maybe I'm reinventing the wheel or doing something totally weird:

```
async Task RunMethod() => await instanceObject.Method();
Task task = RunMethod();
...
try
{
    await task;
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    // handle here
}
```

Comment: That's generally an anti-pattern. It is better to catch and handle exceptions as soon as possible. For example, what if your code fails in `...`? Then the exception from `RunMethod` is lost.

Comment: https://www.bytehide.com/blog/async-await-csharp
This explains async and exception handling well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing is correct. Using async/await is the easiest way to wrap exceptions so that they are thrown asynchronously.

Instead of having a separate async/await helper method that wraps each one of your primary asynchronous methods, you could have a single one and use it everywhere:

```
public static async Task Run(Func<Task> action) => await action();
```

Usage example:

```
Task task = Run(() => instanceObject.DoSomethingAsync());
```

Any exception thrown synchronously by the `DoSomethingAsync`, will be captured inside the resulting `task`.

In case you are wondering how you could implement an identical functionality without using async/await, one way is use the `Task` constructor, and the methods [`RunSynchronously`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.runsynchronously) and [`Unwrap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskextensions.unwrap):

```
public static Task Run(Func<Task> action)
{
    Task<Task> taskTask = new(action, TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach);
    taskTask.RunSynchronously(TaskScheduler.Default);
    return taskTask.Unwrap();
}
```

This `Run` has the exact same behavior¹ with the previous one-liner `Run`, in all three possible scenarios (successful execution, failure, cancellation). The `action` that produces the `Task` is invoked synchronously on the current thread.

¹ <sub>Almost exact. A difference is that in case the `action` fails with multiple exceptions, as it's possible with APIs like the `Task.WhenAll` and `Parallel.ForEachAsync` for example, only the non-`async` version will preserve all exceptions. The `async` version will preserve [only the first exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18314961/i-want-await-to-throw-aggregateexception-not-just-the-first-exception).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest solution would be to pass only "correctly declared" asynchronous methods with `async` keyword. This will throw only on `await`. Please see below example:

```
public static Task MethodWithTask()
{
    throw new Exception();
    return Task.Delay(1000);
}

public static Task MethodWithTask2()
{
    return Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(t => throw new Exception());
}

public static async Task MethodAsync()
{
    throw new Exception();
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}

public static async Task MethodAsync2()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    throw new Exception();
}
```

And now simple method where we could invoke (from your example):

```
public static async Task Test()
{
    var t = MethodWithTask();

    try
    {
        await t;
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}
```

Now let's break donw what will happen:

`var t = MethodWithTask();` - it will throw exception immediately, before code enter `try..catch`, crashing the application,

`var t = MethodWithTask2();` - it will be caught correctly by `catch` clause (obviously),

`var t = MethodAsync();` - **it will be caught correctly by `catch` clause**,

`var t = MethodAsync2();` - it will be caught correctly by `catch` clause (obviously).

**UPDATE**

The other simply solution is to put instantiating of task under `try`, so all immediate exceptions will be caught as well;

```
public static async Task test()
{
    try
    {
        var t = MethodWithTask();
        await t;
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it is the way to go to only use true async methods. But how do you handle async methods from used libraries? OP stated that he could not be sure about the implementation. That's the problem to solve. Your _other simple solution_ does not work if you try to start multiple tasks and await them all late on. The first exception will prevent the new tasks to be started. This approach even works if start of task and await are in the same method.