# How to Await Task.Run(action) when action is unknown

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have the following code:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Run(() => LongProcess()).ContinueWith( t => Run(() => LongerProcess()));

        int count = 5;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine(count.ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            count++;
        } while (count < 20);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void LongProcess()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Long Process 1");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("Long Process 2");
    }

    private static void LongerProcess()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Longer Process 1");
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Console.WriteLine("Longer Process 2");
    }

    private static async Task Run(Action action)
    {

        await Task.Run(action);  //shouldn't this wait until the action is completed??
                                // how should I modify the code so that the program waits until action is done before returning?

    }
```

With the `await Task.Run(action);`, I am expecting that the program will wait until whatever `action` is done, before going on to the next step. In other words, I am expecting outputs like:

```
Long Process 1
Long Process 2
Longer Process 1
Longer Process 2
5
6
7
8
...
19
```

However, the output is like

```
Long Process 1
5
6
7
8
...
19
Long Process 2
Longer Process 1
Longer Process 2
```

Questions:

1. Why isn't `await Task.Run` waits until `action` is completed?
2. How to change the code so that it gives the output that I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `await` does not wait, that is the whole point. If you want to wait, you use `Task.Wait`.

However, the execution of the `async` method will only resume after the awaited task is completed (it is a continuation). Let us see your `async` method:

```
private static async Task Run(Action action)
{

    await Task.Run(action);
    // There is nothing here
}
```

There is no code to execute after the task is done... Alright, the `async` method returns a task that completes when it is done. Let us see if you `await` that...

```
Run(() => LongProcess()).ContinueWith( t => Run(() => LongerProcess()));
```

You don't. You fire that task and forget about it.

---

I think this is what you want:

```
static async void Main(string[] args)
{
    await Run(() => LongProcess());
    await Run(() => LongerProcess());

    int count = 5;
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine(count.ToString());
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        count++;
    } while (count < 20);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Note**: Async Main is a C# 7.1 feature.

This code will run the task that invokes `LongProcess`, and then as a continuation the task that runs `LongerProcess`, and then as a continuation the rest of the code.

*Why would you want that instead of just calling these methods synchronously is beyond me.*

By the way, in an `async` method you can use `await Task.Delay(milliseconds)` instead of `Thread.Sleep(milliseconds)`. The advantage is that the thread is not waiting. *It like making a continuation on a single execution timer.*

---

If `async/await` is just continuations, you might be wondering why would people want to use them instead of `ContinueWith`.

Let me give you a few reasons:

- Code with `async/await` is easier to read. Less nested stuff clouding the code. You can understand what the code does independently of understanding threading.
- Code with `async/await` is easier to write. You just write it as if it were all synchronous, with some `async` and `await` sparkled in there. You can write synchronous code and then worry how to make it concurrent. You also end up writing less, which means you are more productive.
- Code with `async/await` is smarter™. The compiler rewrites your code as a continuation state machine, allowing you to put `await` inside statements without any code gymnastics™. And this extends to exception handling. You see, in your fire and forget task continuation, you are not handling exceptions. What if `LongerProcess` throws? Well, with `async/await` you can just put the `await` inside of a `try ... catch` and it does the right thing™.

That is all good separation of concerns.

---

You may also wonder in what situation it is a good idea to use `async/await` instead of synchronous code. And the answer is that it shines when dealing with I/O operations. When interacting with an external system it is common to not have a response right away. For example, if you want to read from disk or download from the network.

In fact, if you consider manipulating a form and handling its event to be I/O bound operations (because, they are). You will see that they are a good place to use `async/await`. In particular given that the synchronization context for UI threads will keep continuations on the same thread by default. You can, of course, use `async/await` with CPU bound operations by using `Task.Run`. When is that a good idea? Ah, yes, when you want to keep the UI responsive.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent explanation, one thing I'm not clear: " Less nested stuff clouding the code."-- what do you mean? Can illustrate why `ContinueWith` leads to more nesting?

Comment: @Graviton I was thinking of nesting expressions. This `Run(() => LongProcess()).ContinueWith( t => Run(() => LongerProcess()));` already has more nesting than this `await Run(() => LongProcess()); await Run(() => LongerProcess());`. You could, of course, choose to make `LongProcess` and `LongerProcess` async, and then you have `await LongProcessAsync(); await LongerProcessAsync();`.

Comment: @Graviton With that said, if you wanted to use `ContinueWith`, and inside the continuation you want to call some async methods... then you can have some task nesting which would be avoided by simply using `await`. See [C# Chained ContinueWith Not Waiting for Previous Task to Complete](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46235216/402022) for example. Notice that the not nested solution requires `Wait`, meaning that it has some thread wasted in waiting. While the `await` solution is easier to read and does the right thing™.