# Invoke a lambda without creating a delegate; causes CS0149 Method name expected

Tags: c#, lambda

I would like to create a lambda expression and invoke it immediately and I would like to avoid creating a delegate; a trivial example<sup>1</sup>:

```
int i = (() => 42)();
```

This produces the error:

> CS0149 Method name expected

There are two workarounds:

- Declare a (local) method:

  ```
  int Return42() => 42;

  int i = Return42();
  ```
- Create a delegate:

  ```
  int i = ((Func<int>)(() => 42))();
  ```

It is possible to create and immediately invoke a lambda expression without creating a delegate and without naming it?  And if possible, how can one create such a lambda?

---

<sup>1.</sup> <sub>In reality it is an `async` `Task` that I would like to use instead of [`Task.ContinueWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321405(v=vs.110).aspx) (I tried to follow what [Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary) said: [you should strive to replace `ContinueWith` with `await`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18698075/814206)); e.g:</sub>

```
Task<int> future = (async () =>
                       (await RetrieveLookupFromFarAway())["42"].First())();
```

With `RetrieveLookupFromFarAway` something like:

```
async Task<ILookup<string, int>> RetrieveLookupFromFarAway()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    return Enumerable.Empty<int>().ToLookup((x) => x.ToString());
}
```

Comment: The problem is that `() => 42` can be both, a `Func` and an `Expression`. That´s the reason you can´t use `var` to assign it to a variable.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: Or a completely different delegate type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concept of a lambda expression only exists as source code. It doesn't even have a type in itself (just like the `null` literal doesn't have a type). It *has* to be converted to either an expression tree or a delegate: that's what exists as far as the IL and the CLR are concerned. The compiler has to emit code to create *something*, and you need to tell it which type you want that to be.

The compiler doesn't play favourites in terms of delegate types: while it *could* "know" about `Func<T>` and use that as a default delegate type for a lambda expression with no parameters, it doesn't.

The closest you'll get to what you want is to have a convenience method that you can call accepting a `Func<T>`, which could either just *return* the function, or execute it and return the result. For example:

```
public static Func<T> CreateFunc<T>(Func<T> func) => func;
public static T ExecuteFunc<T>(Func<T> func) => func();
```

Then you can call it as:

```
CreateFunc(() => 42)();
```

or

```
ExecuteFunc(() => 42);
```