# Does Task.WhenAll wait for all the tasks in case of exceptions

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I have two tasks. I run both of them with Task.WhenAll. What happens if one of them throws an exception? Would the other one complete?

Comment: If you are interested to a `WhenAll` implementation that fails immediately on first exception, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57313252/how-can-i-await-an-array-of-tasks-and-stop-waiting-on-first-exception) is a relevant question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just run this code to test it:

```
private static async Task TestTaskWhenAll()
{
    try
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(
            ShortOperationAsync(),
            LongOperationAsync()
        );
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exception.Message); // Short operation exception
        Debugger.Break();
    }
}

private static async Task ShortOperationAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    throw new InvalidTimeZoneException("Short operation exception");

}

private static async Task LongOperationAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    throw new ArgumentException("Long operation exception");
}
```

Debugger will stop in 5 seconds. Both exceptions are thrown, but `Debugger.Break()` is hit only once. What is more, the `exception` value is not `AggregateException`, but `InvalidTimeZoneException`. This is because of new `async/await` which does the unwrapping into the actual exception. You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12007781/why-doesnt-await-on-task-whenall-throw-an-aggregateexception). If you want to read other `Exceptions` (not only the first one), you would have to read them from the `Task` returned from `WhenAll` method call.

Comment: What is purpose of `Task.Run` for already asynchronous methods?

Comment: If you really want to block a thread for 1000 msec, `Thread.Sleep(1000)` is simpler than `Task.Delay(1000).Wait()`.

Answer (score 12):

#### Will the other one complete?

It won't be *stopped* as a result of the other one failing.

#### But will it **complete**?

`Task.When` will wait for all to complete, whether any or none fail. I just tested with this to verify - and it took 5 seconds to complete:

```
Task allTasks = Task.WhenAll(getClientToken, getVault, Task.Delay(5000));
```

If you want to group the tasks you can create a 'new task', then await that.

```
Task allTasks = Task.WhenAll(getClientToken, getVault, Task.Delay(5000)); 

try 
{
    await allTasks;

} catch (Exception ex) 
{

   // ex is the 'unwrapped' actual exception
   // I'm not actually sure if it's the first task to fail, or the first in the list that failed

   // Handle all if needed
   Exceptions[] allExceptions = allTasks.Exceptions;

   // OR
   // just get the result from the task / exception
   if (getVault.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted) 
   {
       ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Had the same question and tested by myself. In short:

- It always wait for all tasks to finish.
- The first exception is thrown if there is any after all tasks are finished (crash if you don't catch).
- For *all* exceptions, keep the `Task` instance returned by `Task.WhenAll` and use `Exception.InnerExceptions` property.

Here's my test:

```
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tasks = new[] { Foo1(), Foo2(), Foo3() };

        Task t = null;
        try
        {
            t = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            await t;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{ex.GetType().Name}: {ex.Message}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("All have run.");

        if (t.Exception != null) 
        {
            foreach (var ex in t.Exception.InnerExceptions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{ex.GetType().Name}: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

    }

    static async Task Foo1()
    {
        await Task.Delay(50);
        throw new ArgumentException("zzz");
    }

    static async Task Foo2()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Foo 2");
        throw new FieldAccessException("xxx");
    }

    static async Task Foo3()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            await Task.Delay(200);
            Console.WriteLine("Foo 3");
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
Foo 3
Foo 3
Foo 3
Foo 3
Foo 2
Foo 3
Foo 3
Foo 3
Foo 3
Foo 3
Foo 3
ArgumentException: zzz
All have run.
ArgumentException: zzz
FieldAccessException: xxx
```

Comment: Initializing the task with `Task t = null;` is error prone. `Task t;` is safer because it forces you to initialize the variable inside the try block, otherwise your code won't compile. Also be aware that `t.Exception` will be `null` in most cases (because hopefully the task will be completed successfully most of the time). So your current code will cause a `NullReferenceException` in the success case.

Comment: In my case it wouldn't compile if I use `Task t;` though since the assignment of `t` is inside the `try` block. And yeah, I should have added a null check for `t.Exception`, thanks!

Comment: You are right, my previous suggestion isn't compiling. How about initializing the variable before entering the `try` block? `Task t = Task.WhenAll(tasks);` Otherwise you should also check for the case that `t == null` to be 100% safe, which is easy to forget.

Comment: the observation is good but this sample is not entirely correct; construct the tasks in a manner that when they are iterated on, they are run/scheduled -- i.e. LazyLoading with `IEnumerable`.  Your code is current running/scheduling 3 tasks by invocation when defining that array of tasks then -- using the `Task.WhenAll` -- you're ensure those running tasks are completed in execution flow.  Instead, have `Task.WhenAll` perform the execution of runnable tasks;  `var runnableTasks = new [] { Foo1, Foo2, Foo3}.Select(async (fn) => await fn())` then `var t = Task.WhenAll(runnableTasks);`

Comment: if you added `await Task.Delay(10000);` just after `var tasks = new[] { Foo1(), Foo2(), Foo3() };` I believe you'll observe they are running.

Comment: screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/3a1ps0L of that tasks running;  Having said that, your observation is still valid, but the behavior on whether or not `Task.WhenAll` can **ever** handle faulting tasks (without ContinueWith) may depend on whether the IEnumerable tasks are 'loaded' or running/awaiting/scheduled prior it's usage.  also, of course, running of `Foo1()` via invocation could cause an exception to raise outside of your exception handling block (if you `await Task.Delay` prior to try-catch) in your sample.