# Invoke event asynchronously and catching exceptions without stopping other tasks from running

Tags: c#, events, async-await, invoke

Given the following code:

```
public delegate Task AsyncEventHandler<in TEventArgs>(object sender, TEventArgs eventArgs);

public static Task InvokeAsync(this AsyncEventHandler eventHandler, object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    if (eventHandler == null) return Task.CompletedTask;

    var delegates = eventHandler.GetInvocationList().Cast<AsyncEventHandler>();
    var tasks = delegates.Select(it => it.Invoke(sender, eventArgs));

    return Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

I have a test function whereby the faulty handlers should throw exceptions, and the workinghanlder should run - currently only the first FaultyHandler1 is called and no others event handlers.

```
private class NonGenericNotifier
{
    public event AsyncEventHandler SomethingHappened;
    public Task OnSomethingHappening() => SomethingHappened.InvokeAsync(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}

public async Task Multiple_Exceptions_That_Occur_During_Event_Handling_Should_Be_Propagated()
{
    var isHandler1Called = false;
    var isHandler2Called = false;
    var isWorkingHandlerCalled = false;

    var notifier = new NonGenericNotifier();

    Task FaultyHandler1(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        isHandler1Called = true;
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    Task FaultyHandler2(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        isHandler2Called = true;
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    Task WorkingHandler(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        isWorkingHandlerCalled = true;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    notifier.SomethingHappened += FaultyHandler1;
    notifier.SomethingHappened += FaultyHandler2;
    notifier.SomethingHappened += WorkingHandler;

    await Should.ThrowAsync<InvalidOperationException>(async () => await notifier.OnSomethingHappening());
    isHandler1Called.ShouldBe(true);
    isHandler2Called.ShouldBe(true);
    isWorkingHandlerCalled.ShouldBe(true);
}
```

Assuming a single exception can be thrown I beleive this should be an `AggregateException` containing an exception for each Task, and most importantly the `InvokeAsync` method above should bail on the first exception encountered.

I have started to create a `List<Exception>` within the `InvokeAsync` extension method, and wrap each `it => it.Invoke(sender, eventArgs)` with a `try/catch` construct and within the catch add the exception to the exception list.

However I am lost on how to collate this list of exceptions and then send on as an `AggregateException`.

**UPDATE (FIX?)**

Thanks to Artur for pointing me in the right direction. I changed the `InvokeAsync` extension method to the below, and it *works* - no longer halting on the first task. We have gone from `var tasks = delegates.Select(it => it.Invoke(sender, eventArgs));` to the below using the [code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12007781/why-doesnt-await-on-task-whenall-throw-an-aggregateexception):

```
public static Task InvokeAsync(this AsyncEventHandler eventHandler, object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    if (eventHandler == null) return Task.CompletedTask;

    var delegates = eventHandler.GetInvocationList().Cast<AsyncEventHandler>();
    var tasks = delegates.Select(async it => await it.Invoke(sender, eventArgs));

    return Task.WhenAll(tasks).WithAggregatedExceptions();
}

static Task WithAggregatedExceptions(this Task task)
{
    // using AggregateException.Flatten as a bonus
    return task.ContinueWith(
        continuationFunction: priorTask =>
            priorTask.IsFaulted &&
            priorTask.Exception is AggregateException ex && (ex.InnerExceptions.Count > 1 || ex.InnerException is AggregateException) ? Task.FromException(ex.Flatten()) : priorTask,
        cancellationToken: CancellationToken.None,
        TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously,
        scheduler: TaskScheduler.Default).Unwrap();
}
```

My issue is subscribers of this event, writing synchronous handlers over which I have no control - this would stop the other event handlers (sync and async) running that are attached to the same event.

I also appreciate this is the designed function of `Task.WhenAll` if you were mixing async and non-async handlers... if there is one reason to not write synchronous code in an async function without `await Task.Yield()` this is it.

**Question**

Can we say that wrapping the `delegates.Select(async it => await it.Invoke(sender, eventArgs)` with async/await allows synchronous method to run, and at *worst(?)* wrap twice an async method (which is the same as nesting async/await function calls) so is actually a non-issue?

Are there any side effects that have been introduced?

With the bounty looking for authorative guidance on how this would be implemented, one answer (much appreciated for contributing to the discussion) says to avoid async events, yet in other places like the discord c# client they have embraced async events (with timeout wrappers etc).

Comment: The problem is that your handlers are synchronous. If you check the implementation of [Task.WhenAll](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs#L6009), you will see that your tasks are enumerated before being wrapped with [WhenAllPromise](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs#L6074). `WhenAll` throws immediately after executing the first task before even reaching the other in the list. Try to add `await Task.Yield();` before throwing an exception and you will see the expected result

Comment: Thanks @Artur add async and await in the `delegates` enumerable seems to fix this?

Comment: Yes, it seems to do the work. Not sure throwing `AggregatedException` is a good idea as developers expect to get a concrete exception from awaited code. If you still want to provide all available information about failed handlers, better create a custom exception similar to `AggregatedException` and throw it instead.

Comment: @morleyc Sorry but it is unclear after your update what is your question?

Comment: Peter, fair point, have updated and sharded off what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Task.WhenAll` will invoke all the handlers when it reifies its parameter. It will invoke them one at a time, and then will asynchronously wait for all the tasks to complete.

The reason you were seeing the halting on the first exception was because the exception was thrown *during* reification. It's normal for asynchronous (Task-returning) functions to place any exceptions on the returned task. It's abnormal for asynchronous functions to throw exceptions directly.

So, this is the problematic code:

```
Task FaultyHandler1(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
  isHandler1Called = true;
  throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
```

One of these would be correct:

```
async Task FaultyHandler1(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
  isHandler1Called = true;
  throw new InvalidOperationException();
}

Task FaultyHandler1(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
  isHandler1Called = true;
  return Task.FromException(new InvalidOperationException());
}
```

You're seeing the odd behavior because the asynchronous handler is misbehaving (by throwing a synchronous exception).

Now, if you *want* to allow misbehaving asynchronous handlers, you *can* do that, either with an explicit `try`/`catch` or the extra `async`/`await`:

```
var tasks = delegates.Select(it => try { return it.Invoke(sender, eventArgs); } catch (Exception ex) { return Task.FromException(ex); });

// async/await is necessary to handle misbehaving asynchronous handlers that throw synchronous exceptions
var tasks = delegates.Select(async it => await it.Invoke(sender, eventArgs));
```

If you do keep the `async`/`await` approach, please do comment it, because coding constructs like that are often assumed to be spurious and may be removed by a future maintainer.

The `WithAggregatedExceptions` looks fine as-is, but it can be simplified if you want:

```
static async Task WithAggregatedExceptions(this Task task)
{
  try { await task; }
  catch { throw task.Exception; }
}
```

> My issue is subscribers of this event, writing synchronous handlers over which I have no control - this would stop the other event handlers (sync and async) running that are attached to the same event.

Well, yes. `Task.WhenAll` reifies its collection of tasks synchronously, which invokes all the handlers one at a time.

If you want to allow synchronous handlers as well as asynchronous ones all at the same time, you *can* wrap the invocations in a `Task.Run`:

```
var tasks = delegates.Select(it => Task.Run(() => it.Invoke(sender, eventArgs)));
```

> Can we say that wrapping the delegates.Select(async it => await it.Invoke(sender, eventArgs) with async/await allows synchronous method to run, and at worst(?) wrap twice an async method (which is the same as nesting async/await function calls) so is actually a non-issue?

The extra `async`/`await` for asynchronous handlers is a non-issue; it's very slightly less efficient, and *appears* unnecessary, so I'd say it's in danger of being removed (unless commented). It doesn't "allow synchronous methods to run"; instead, it corrects the misbehaving methods that throw exceptions directly instead of placing them on the returned Task as expected.

> Are there any side effects that have been introduced?

Not really. If you do use the `Task.Run` approach, then all the handlers are invoked on thread pool threads and may run concurrently, which may be surprising.

> one answer (much appreciated for contributing to the discussion) says to avoid async events, yet in other places like the discord c# client they have embraced async events (with timeout wrappers etc).

I am 100% in agreement with that answer.

Here's how I think about it:

The Observer pattern is a way to notify observers of state changes. The Observer pattern is a clear fit for "events" in OOP: any number of observers may subscribe to state change notifications. This is what C# events were patterned after: notifying subscribers of things. There's no mechanism for information to "flow back". While the language *allows* C# events with return values, it's not *natural* by any means. The same limitation happens with exceptions (which can be considered a kind of return): the standard `handler?.Invoke` pattern starts to break (stopping invocations at the first exception, etc).

As soon as you have information "flowing back" (including needing to handle exceptions, or needing to `await` all the handlers to complete), you're no longer in the Observer pattern, and you are no longer in the happy path of C# events.

Generally, I find most "events" of this type are usually related to a Strategy or Visitor pattern, rather than Observer. Neither Strategy nor Visitor are good fits for C# events, although they are often (sadly) implemented that way. I consider that a common design mistake (for all OOP languages).

Comment: Let's suppose we use the `Task.Run` approach. And we have the following code: `Task allFinished = Task.WhenAll(tasks); try { await allFinished; } catch { ... }` then the `allFinished.Exception` contains all the thrown exceptions. But all the `Task`s inside the `tasks` is in `WaitingForActivation` status. Why?

Comment: If we use `async` `await` inside the `Select` then we would have two Tasks with `Faulted` and one with `RanToCompletion` status.

Comment: @PeterCsala: The `tasks` enumerable is reified *within* `Task.WhenAll`. If you enumerate `tasks` afterwards, it will start new tasks because enumerables are lazily evaulated. If you want to examine `tasks` after `WhenAll`, then reify it yourself by doing a `ToList()` after the `Select`.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the design of using C# events in an async way is not robust, and it will always behave in a slightly uncontrolled way. There are better techniques to make event processing robust.

One of the best such technologies is TPL Dataflows (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library). This library allows you to program stream processing in a very controlled way, it helps you deal with task schedulers etc. Once you apply this successfully, all the problems in your question will be addressed.

There are obviously other alternatives out there, but I would clearly abstain from re-implementing this by using C# events....